# Is it possible to observe a boolean till change? (C#)

Tags: c#, methods, boolean

So I have

```
boolean variableName = false
```

Is it possible to write a event (observeVariableName) that is "observing" variableName all the time till it changes to true and when it is on true the event does something? Like for example:

```
public void observeVariableName() //triggers when variableName == true
{
// do actions here
variableName = false
}
```

Comment: Can you put this boolean inside a class? Are you talking about a simple C# script?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible just with having a boolean variable. You can wrap that value in a class and add an event there, if you want the event to be triggered every time the value changes, you can do it in the `setter` method of the property.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use implement [interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your class that contains your boolean.

For exemple,

```
    public class DemoCustomer : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private bool _selected;
        public bool Selected
        {
            get
            {
                return _selected;
            }
            set
            {
                _selected = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Selected");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property.
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument.
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
```

Then, you listen this event.

```
var d = new DemoCustomer();
d.PropertyChanged += (s,e) => { if(e.PropertyName = "Selected" && ((DemoCustomer)s).Selected) { //do something}};
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use *property* `variableName`.

```
public bool variableName {
   get {
      return variableName;
   }
   set {
      variableName = value;
      if (value)
          // do stuff;
   }
}
```

Look for [instructions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_properties.htm).

Comment: What this got to do with the question?

Comment: Agree with you. I thought it could be helpful in this case.

Comment: If it isn't an answer it should be a comment.

Comment: Its the same answer as Selmans, Alex suggested to use property instead of variable so you can raise event inside setter method.